# How gravity affects ball rolling on horizontal flat surface?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, friction, projectile

I have one set up where the **golf ball** is rolling on the **flat grass surface** table.

Due to **friction** of the grass surface, the ball should **stop** after sometime.

Is there a chance that the ball will keep rolling because of the **gravitational** **force**?

I would appreciate any suggestions and thoughts on this topic.

**EDIT:**

I am a game developer and trying to simulate real world **mini golf** game. I have game setup similar to the real world. But in my game world, after applying little force the ball continuous to roll at slow speed. [Graph of ball speed over time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewBZQ.png).

Hence, I wanted to have suggestions whether in the real world whether gravity can create such scenario.

Comment: Why do you think gravity will exert a force in the forward direction?

Comment: I am a game developer and trying to simulate real world mini golf game. I have game setup similar to real world. But in my game world, after applying little force the ball continuous to roll at slow speed. Hence, I wanted to have suggestions whether in the real world whether gravity can create such scenario.

Comment: You do not define whether the plot you link is from your real table.  For gravity not to have an influence you have to use a completely horizontal table.  Use a spirit level. If you see  no stop  a) your balls are too heavy for the friction offered by the grass, or your grass too thin.

Comment: Yes, the plot is completely horizontal. The ball is 45 grams in weight and the grass friction is affecting the ball motion most of the time but after certain value of the ball velocity, the ball continues to roll. Please refer to the graph.

Comment: Might [gamedev.se] be better suited for this question?

Comment: True. However, I wanted to check the real world physics rules.

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that the grass is perfectly flat, it will be perpendicular to the centre of the earth at all points. So, the gravitational force will not do any work on the ball, and it won't keep moving.

If you take into account objects other than the earth, these will have a minuscule effect; nowhere near the earth's. The friction will negate these many times over - so no, gravitational forces will not make the ball keep rolling.

Comment: This is assuming a horizontal table - it's blindingly obvious that if the table is vertical then it won't stop...

Answer (score -1):

Gravitational force is what "creates" friction in the first place. But it's also due to the friction that ball continues to roll and not just spin in a single place. So in some sense, yes - the ball is rolling thanks to gravitational force.

However, I suspect you were asking whether there's an additional input? If the surface is completely flat, you will not have any other gravitational input. Even if you consider the ball as non point-like, the gravitational force on it still acts equally at the side it's rolling to and at the side it's rolling from because of "flatness" you mentioned, thus balancing the force.